# Human evolution on Exoplanet

Tags: planets, evolution, humans, science-fiction

Let's imagine that an advanced alien civilization came to visit us about 200,000 years ago, and that they kidnapped a human group at the beginning of the development of the homo sapiens species.

They placed this human group on an exoplanet with the same specifications as the Earth (with a "exo-animal" population already present, ...), and then allowed them to develop on their own.

By excluding any possibility of interference by the said alien civilization, what could be the social, technological, biological or physical characteristics of this exo-human civilization (compared to our present civilization) in 2017?

I'm not talking about human colonization of space but how humans species could evolve isolated in differents places like :

- Could the exo-humans be on the same technological level as humans on Earth?
- What could be their social organisation, considering that they've never been in contact with Earth humans ?
- Would they be biologically or physically the same as Earth humans ?
- ...

Thanks for you help !

Comment: This is an extremely open question. If you took a group of hominids from 200,000 years ago and moved them to another place *on Earth* they would evolve a bit differently. If you move them to another planet, all bets are off. Could you be more specific about the planet you have in mind?

Comment: @Mołot Possibly related but not a duplicate.

Comment: @a4android we will see if it is a duplicate or not, when OP will edit this down and make it less broad.

Comment: @pablodf76 I was thinking about a planet with the same characteristics that Earth, like a twin Earth.

Comment: No need to relocate them to another planet. Relocating them to the Americas would be enough. The results would be completely unpredictable. Remember that the _entire history_, from the beginnigs in Sumer to our wondrous days, is not longer than 7000 years. What would happen over a timespan of 200 millennia is impossible to guess.

Comment: @AlexP I choose the "other planet" scenario as a pretext to explain why these two population would not have met in such a long time. I know 200 millennia is very long, that's why I would like to hear some theories about that.

Comment: @AlexP Not impossible to guess at all. They will pass through their own versions of the Palaeolithic & Neolithic. fairly readily understood from archaeology, it's once they develop agriculture, cities, writing, & post-Neolithic technology, that's when the major divergences will occur. Now geography & history make things generally unpredictable, certain trends & developments can be anticipated though. Now the OP has to play God.

Comment: @Molot "Marked as an exact duplicate"??? Did anyone read the purported duplicate question? Did I and an exact duplicate it is not. Perhaps the question can be improved, then it wouldn't hurt to make suggestions for its improvement.

Comment: @a4android: Human societies are the ultimate chaotic systems. The essence of chaotic systems is that tikny variations in the initial conditions can result in large variations in the final conditions. Suppose that their palaeolithic takes 500 years less than ours and as a result their are now 500 years more advanced: how society will look like is impossible to tell. Or maybe their social conditions are such that steam power becomes useful in their version of antiquity. Etc. Etc. Look at the difference between the Old World and the New in the 16th century after 20 millenia of separation.

Comment: @AlexP Not much more so than weather and climate. Over enough time differences smooth out. The real differences will be in culture and social organization. Technology is ultimately limited by nature. Culture is radically divergent, path dependent and highly contingent on context. This why the OP has step in shape the results he wants. This isn't a start here with A & get results B by time t process. But you already know that, naturally.

Comment: @a4android word "exact" was removed from the close reason few years ago. That was on purpose, to allow closing similar questions with identical answers, if both are written in a way that force identical answers.

Comment: @Molot. That's good that it was removed. Unfortunately, it still says "This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question." Right there under the names of close voters. A little fix may be needed. I understand the concept of forcing identical answers even if the questions were worded differently. Having read both questions and their answers they're obviously related but not duplicates. OK, we can disagree here and now we can move on to better things.

Comment: So maybe it would be "better" to close it as too broad (because it is, being many questions in one), without pointing op to where some parts are already answered. There were "too broad" votes on this all right. But it seems more people think that marking duplicate is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem with your idea is that at the beginning of  the Homo Sapiens group of species, 200,000 would have been a large part of the total population.

Estimates suggest that 10,000 years ago the entire population was only 2 million.

Homo Sapiens started before that.

So removing 200,000 homo sapiens early on would have been close to devastating the population.

The second problem is that homo sapiens at that time, lacking any technology or support and placed into an alien ecosystem which they were not adapted to would be extremely vulnerable.  It's unlikely they could survive either medically (any indigenous pathogen might be lethal to them) or simply as a matter of finding food they could eat.

Even if your aliens picked a planet "safe" for them (in itself a scenario that is unlikely to be practically possible) they would still be removed from their own environment - the one they were adapted to survive in, before they developed the technological and social skills required for such adaptation.

I'd be very skeptical they could survive at all.

It's impossible to say what their current social, biological and physical characteristics could be even if they survived.  They'd probably be roughly the same shape and size and there's little time for evolutionary changes of a major kind to happen.

However to survive they'd probably have to develop an immune system that was targeted at different systems from ours.  It's simply that their environment would throw different things at them.

As as side note I've speculated that the reason aliens don't contact or visit us is simply because for a less technologically advanced civilization all an alien culture can do for you is expose you to potentially deadly pathogens.  So why your aliens would risk such a thing is, for me, a mystery.

At best I'd expect the 200,000 seed population to be reduced to a much smaller population very rapidly by pathogens.  The survivors, who would have developed some immunity, might grow but the smaller the seed population, the less likely their continued survival and the smaller their current population would be.

As they're humans they'd be prone to the same problems we are : war, internal competition for scare resources, dispute and identification with sub-groups leading to conflict with other sub-groups.  Assuming they could survive they'd probably have a smaller population than we do (say the tens of millions ballpark) and be at roughly the 4000 B.C. cultural/technological mark (based on the size of the starting population, time to develop and likely early loss due to pathogens).

The specifics of such a culture are impossible to even guesstimate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I find the second part of your answer very interesting, you're talking a lot about how the population can influence the level of evolution. 
You're saying (correct me if I'm wrong) that because the exo-humans population would be lower, their level of development would also be lower : what could happens if the starting population of exo-humans would be twice as large as Earth humans population ? Could they be more developed than us ?

Comment: Taking more people from Earth's population would probably reduce the Earth's population level to dangerously low levels.  But even taking more people will not help as much as (in my view) the transported population would be near wiped out by at least one pathogen (I think a 10% survival rate is a good guess).  Say you take a million people, that still only gets you a measly 100,000 survivors.  It will simply take them longer to develop than the (say) 500,00 left on Earth (their natural environment).  It's the colonized planet's potential to kill that is the problem.